# how to upload to server and save image in Sd card using asynk task in android

Tags: android

```
class Uploadimage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        InputStream inputStream;
        private static final String ALLOWED_URI_CHARS = "@#&=*+-_.,:!?()/~'%";

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setTitle("Updating...");
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                String Url = Uri.encode(
                        "http://api.lociiapp.com/api/registration/ProfilePictureSaved?imageFile="
                                + params[0] + "&member_id=" + member_id
                                + "&picture_path=" + member_id + ".jpg",
                        ALLOWED_URI_CHARS);

                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(Url);

                httppost.setHeader(
                        "Accept",
                        "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml,application/json;q=0.9,/;q=0.8");
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                System.out.println("15aug " + result);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                pDialog.cancel();
                System.out.println("Error in http connection " + e.toString());
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog.cancel();

            MtDrawableManager.getInstance().fetchBitmapOnThread(image_Url,
                    Profile_image);

            Log.e("Image Url**************", image_Url);

        }

    }
```

This is my code using this code i am able to Upload Image to server i want  using same asynk task image should move to sd card in device i.e when i select image from gallery and camera then image should upload to server and at time that image should move to sd card please tell me how i will implement this i have tried but unable to do this please help .

Answer (score 0):

Check fot  response.getStatusCode(). If its HTTP_OK you can call below code to save image in phone memory

```
private String saveToInternalSorage(Bitmap bitmapImage){
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
         // path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir
        File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // Create imageDir
        File mypath=new File(directory,"profile.jpg");

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {           

            fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);

       // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
            bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return directory.getAbsolutePath();
    }
```

Comment: this code we ll use in do in background or on Post excute?

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/qdAES2PvXwXLNSD9F2fNRw this code i am using for download image  to sd card but same image is downloading

Comment: doInBackground should be used as it runs on worker thread , while onPostExecute runs on Main thread. And saving images to memroy is time consuming process , so it should be used in worker thread i.e saving image should be done in doInBackground

Comment: @Edge : Are you doing some bimap operations on images at server ? If not then you can use the code which i shared with you as its well tested code.

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
     .toString() + "/LociiImages/" directory will like this na?

Comment: Yes. @Edge you are going correct. The above code will save images on your app structure with in phone memory.

Comment: Ok thanx wait let me try i will get back to u

Comment: Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("http://api.lociiapp.com/TransientStorage/"
      + member_id + ".jpg");
    
    saveToInternalSorage(bm);  this code i m using doinbackgroun but file size is 0byte save to sdcard

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67830/discussion-between-roll-no1-and-edge).

Comment: please check where am doing mistake

Comment: click on above link which i shared with you some time back. I am already at chat room